# Increment the the element of the arrayList at particular position

Tags: java

I am finding the largest difference between the arrayList `minuteList` element then am incrementing the element with `min_value` after this position to refill the timetable. With the current the same element is always being added.

**minuteList bevore the while statement:**

```
[288, 318, 346, 376, 406, 436, 466, 1006, 1036, 1066, 1096, 1126, 1156]
```

**minuteList` after a few loops:**

```
[288, 318, 346, 376, 406, 436, 466, 496, 496, 496, 496, 1006, 1036, 1066, 1096, 1126, 1156]
```

**Correct result should looks like**

```
[288, 318, 346, 376, 406, 436, 466, 496, 526, 556, 586, 616,..., 1006, 1036, 1066, 1096, 1126, 1156]
```

**Code:**

```
Collections.sort(diffArray);

int element = diffArray.get(diffArray.size() - 1).getElement();
int nextElement = diffArray.get(diffArray.size()-1).getNextElement();

int differance = nextElement - element;

int elementIndex = minuteList.indexOf(element);

while(differance > min_value){
    int addTime = minuteList.get(elementIndex) + min_value;
    minuteList.add(elementIndex + 1, addTime);

}
```

Comment: Where are you facing the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop keeps adding the same value (`minuteList.get(elementIndex) + min_value`) to the same position (`elementIndex + 1`) of the `ArrayList`, which explains the multiple 496 elements you see.

If you wish a new value to be added in each iteration, you need `addTime` to change in each iteration :

```
int addTime = minuteList.get(elementIndex) + min_value;
while(differance > min_value){
    minuteList.add(++elementIndex, addTime);
    addTime += min_value;
}
```

Note that I'm also incrementing `elementIndex`. Otherwise, all the new elements will be added at the same position, pushing the previously added elements forward, so they'll be added in reverse order.

You might want to add some code inside the loop that actually modifies `differance` or `min_value`. Otherwise the loop will never end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but why the first element is not being  added at the begging I am getting this array `[288, 318, 346, 376, 406, 436, 466, 526, 556, 1006, 1036, 1066, 1096, 1126, 1156]` also  `496` is missing?

Comment: It is better to but this line `int addTime = minuteList.get(elementIndex) + min_value;` inside the loop.

Comment: @MrAsker Oh, I see my mistake. I'm adding `min_value` twice to `addTime` before adding the first element. See edited code.